# Teamcity Configuration Settings

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I need to know the teamcity settings which prevents the re-trigger/trigger of outdated builds/jobs if the new builds are successful.

I am facing a issue where teamcity jobs can be re triggered even if the next builds are successful.And If the trigger event is fired before, then it must stop teamcity to run that job if the latest build is successful.

So I have to 2 jobs in TC for 1 branch -- Build-Precheck and the other is Build-compile

So I could see that Build-compile is just picking the latest available successful build from Build-Precheck and then queing up the next which may be the outdated build.

Build-Precheck is just taking 2 min to finish the builds , it quickly triggers the latest builds , I guess following the principal First In First Out 
Build-Precheck
06 Oct 14 14:33 - 14:35 (2m:01s) –7.1.4345
06 Oct 14 14:41 - 14:43 (2m:16s)- 7.1.4346
06 Oct 14 14:45 - 14:47 (2m:10s)- 7.1.4347
Build-compile
06 Oct 14 14:35 - 15:00 -7.1.0.4345
06 Oct 14 14:52 - 15:20 (28m:02s)- 7.1.4347
06 Oct 14 16:08 - 16:33 (24m:52s)- 7.1.4346

Is there any fix for this that TC runs incremental builds rather than outdated ones

Comment: What triggers do you have setup? Very hard to answer given the limited information provided.

Comment: There is a Finish Build Trigger set up which allows the job to run after a particular configuration gets successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [Configuring Build Trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Triggers).

AFAIK, there isn't a way to cancel queued builds if a given build passes.  However, you can adjust the Build Triggers that queue those builds.  Most likely, you'll need to set the [Quiet Period](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-QuietPeriodSettings) on your VCS Build Trigger to longer than it takes for your build.

For example, if your full build takes 5 minutes, you should set the Quiet Period to 7.  This way additional builds wont queue while a build is running.

Comment: Did you set an appropriate quiet period on the build trigger?

Comment: A quiet period is a period (in seconds) that TeamCity maintains between the moment the last VCS change is detected and a build is added into the queue. In My case I need to queue the builds in increasing order for Build Compile not just the random order